# Basic RMI Example

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying out a basic RMI example .But whenever I run the service I get the following error

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 116.203.202.217; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.bind(Naming.java:111)
at rmi.remote.RemteImpl.main(RemteImpl.java:29)
```

Here is the code

```
package rmi.remote;

import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class RemteImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RemoteIntf{

protected RemteImpl() throws RemoteException {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public String sayHello() throws RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "hi";
}

public static void main(String a[])
{
    try {
        RemoteIntf service=new RemteImpl();
        Naming.bind("Remote",service);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

I am using windows 7 OS

Comment: It can't get much clearer than `Connection timed out` I think....  Are you sure the other party is listening and reachable, and that your firewall isn't blocking you?

Comment: it seems the port is in use, or you have firewall issues

Comment: @user2511414 Connection timeouts are not caused by port in use problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your bind string is incorrect. It should be "rmi://localhost/Remote". And you should also check your 'hosts' file to make sure it maps "localhost" to 127.0.0.1, and your real hostname to your real host address.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your RMI registry is not running, which is causing the bind call to fail. You are also not binding to a URL but just to a name.

Usually you'd call bind like so:

```
Naming.bind("//registryHost:port/remote", service);
```

where registryHost points at the machine that is running your RMI registry.

For a simple local test you'd make the URL "//localhost:port/remote" and run the rmiregistry service on your local machine.

How to do this is explained for example here:
http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/javarmi/javarmi.html

Excerpt:
To start the registry, Windows users should do the following (assuming that your java\bin directory is in the current path):-

start rmiregistry 
To start the registry, Unix users should do the following:-

rmiregistry &

Comment: That would cause 'connection refused', not a connect timeout. You can only bind to a registry running in the local host, so there is never any point in specifying anything other than 'local host' when binding, rebinding, or unbinding.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class RemteImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RemoteIntf{
```

from RemoteInf is a interface which implements Remote, so, in your main code

```
  RemoteIntf service=new RemteImpl(); //avoid this
```

//priort to adding this also consider to make sure you have initialized security Manager for allowing connection from or all given IP address.

```
 RemoteImpl service = new RemoteImpl();
```

should be changed to

```
 RemoteInt service = new RemoteImpl();
```

where a server object is needed. After that , create a server registry in your code if don't want to use rmiregistry.

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(*port*);
```

finally, bind the service to a url where a rmi service is provided, using

```
String url = "rmi://127.0.0.1/RemoteObjectRegisteration"  ; //or (your remote ip
```

address on place of 127.0.0.1)

```
Naming.bind(url, service);
```

and the server side should be okay. and  You should take some time learning how to ask questions in stack overflow.........

Comment: There is no evidence here that the Registry isn't running, and there is no difference before and after the change you suggest apart from your numerous typos. -1